# Container or VM for testing Windows software applications

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, docker, sandbox

I’m looking for some suggestions on how I can test some software applications without committing to installing them on my main OS.

I thought a virtual machine would be a good idea, but then I found out that you need a separate Windows license for each physical or virtual installation.

As far as I know, docker containers don’t run gui / desktop applications and sandbox tools require you to install the software on your main OS first, but run separately.

My only solution so far is to run a Linux VM but I’d prefer to stick to Windows if possible.

Comment: Any virtualization unless you used the trial Windows VMs will require a separate Windows license. Windows Sandbox might accomplish what you want.

Comment: Windows runs just fine without a license for a VM instance [oops, did I say that out loud?]

Comment: See [Get a Windows 11 development environment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/). You get a 3-months evaluation VM that is pretty loaded with software.

Answer (score 0):

A Virtual Machine is (based on my experience and knowledge) better than a container, because a VM is more flexible.

Yes, an operating system in a VM needs to be licensed properly.

However, in a VM, you can make a base machine, make a backup copy, test, and if something goes amiss, restore from backup. Very handy feature.

Windows Sandbox goes away on restart or shutdown, so is not a good choice for your work.